# How to test algorithm for solving ECDL in SageMath for a small integer?

Tags: python, sage

The problem I have is to implement the baby-step giant-step or Pollard Rho in SageMath or Python to generate a small multiplier x of G for the given P so that P = x * G.

This is for an assignment part of a larger project.

```
modi =  115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663

E=EllipticCurve(GF(modi), [0,7])

G=E(55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240, 32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424)

P=E(69335761065767984070318781108127416310968753866933119760392423089576366173459, 113425617697416972613102767146321902225172329004525144463444008550345431352693)
```

x=24734216105351567

The search should be limited to a space of 2^54 points for x and solve P = x * G keeping all the other parameters from above.

I tried https://github.com/qubd/mini_ecdsa and I am getting the error below.

```
>>>C = CurveOverFp(0, 0, 7, 2**256-2**32-2**9-2**8-2**7-2**6-2**4-1)
y^2 = x^3 + 7 over F_115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663

>>> P = Point(55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240,
... 32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424)

>>> n = 2^54

>>> Q = (69335761065767984070318781108127416310968753866933119760392423089576366173459, 113425617697416972613102767146321902225172329004525144463444008550345431352693)

>>>crack_baby_giant(C, P, n, Q)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mini_ecdsa.py", line 470, in crack_baby_giant
    R = curve.add(Q, curve.invert(curve.mult(P, g*m)))
  File "mini_ecdsa.py", line 321, in add
    y_diff = (P_2.y - P_1.y) % self.char
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to just use a tuple for `Q`.  But that isn't going to work if a `Point` is expected, as the documentation at the Github link indicates.  Try doing `Q = Point(... , ...)` and hopefully that will work.

---

By the way, probably you were supposed to implement it on your own, not with the other code - or was that provided as an example?  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got rid of the error. I can use any code, as long as it works. But now it gets stuck so I assume the algorithm is searching a large range which is not feasible. I think I have to make the final command `crack_baby_giant(C, P, n, Q)` to search for the solution only within a limited range like between 2^53 and 2^54. I guess it searches all the possible 2^54 solutions now and it runs out of memory. Any idea how to specify a `search range`?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with that custom code you are using.  Sorry.  I do think that there are implementations of the baby/giant in Sage proper of one kind or another.